# Display a list of Buttons when user presses a Button on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that uses the following XAML.

```
<StackLayout Grid.RowSpan="8" 
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     >
          <Label Text="{Binding ActiveMenu.ChildMenuItems.Count}" />
        <ListView x:Name="weapponType"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveMenu.ChildMenuItems}"
                  BackgroundColor="Blue"
                 >
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell >
                  <Button Text="{Binding Text}"
                          FontSize="14"
                          />
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
```

It displays a list of Buttons as follows

```
---- EVENT
-----PROG
-----STAT
-----MENU1
-----MENU2
```

When the user clicks `EVENT` I want it to display a list of buttons

```
---Button1
---Button2
---Button3
```

where

```
<Button x:Name="MenuBtn1" Text="Btn1" Command="{Binding Command1}"
<Button x:Name="MenuBtn2" Text="Btn2" Command="{Binding Command2}"
<Button x:Name="MenuBtn3" Text="Btn3" Command="{Binding Command3}"
```

It would be really great if someone can guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: you would (probably) want to create a 2nd page, and when the user clicks on the Button on the first page, Navigate to the 2nd page.

Comment: @How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/

Comment: @Jason - I have created another page. How do I load the page on a button click?

Comment: @jason - I am getting `PUSHASYNC IS NOT SUPPORTED GLOBALLY ON ANDROID, PLEASE USE A NAVIGATION PAGE.... `

Comment: Have you thought about maybe, perhaps, using a navigation page ? :) This is very, very basic Xamarin.Forms navigation stuff that you can find in a million tutorials, covered in their how to basic guides, on SO documentation, all over the place! You have to be willing to try and look for the info you need, not just wait for someone to solve your problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

u need add the click event "OnBtClick" for each button as follow code:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:ListViewMode.All}" RowHeight="100">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <Button Text="{Binding BtName}" Clicked="OnBtClick"></Button>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

At the code behind:

```
 async void OnBtClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Button {

                            Text = "button1"
                        },
                        new Button {

                           Text = "button2"
                        },
                        new Button {

                            Text = "button3"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

When you click the each button it will show the three button I defined above.

Comment: the "new Contantpage()" could be any ".xmal" page you defined